# Como puedo mostrar en un modal, los detalles de un pin de un mapa de Leaflet

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

Estoy desarrollando un mapa en **LeafLet** y **Laravel 6**. Desde una ruta cargo todos los marcadores que después muestro en el mapa.

En el controlador tengo este método con el que obtengo todos los marcadores publicados.

```
public function getInstallations(){
    $installations = Installation::where('status', 'PUBLISHED')->get();

    $data = [];
    foreach ($installations as $key => $value) {
        $data[$key + 1] = [
            'id' => $value->id,
            'uuid' => $value->uuid,
            'user_id' => $value->user_id,
            'category_id' => $value->category_id,
            'company' => $value->company,
            'name' => $value->name,
            'lat' => $value->lat,
            'lng' => $value->lng,
            'description' => $value->description,
            'on_grid' => $value->on_grid,
            'created_at' => $value->created_at,
            'pin' => $value->pin,
        ];
    }
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

Luego en la vista en la parte de JS hago lo siguiente:

```
var map = L.map('mapid').setView([{{ config('leaflet.map_center_latitude') }}, {{ config('leaflet.map_center_longitude') }}], {{ config('leaflet.zoom_level') }});

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);
```

Las variables

```
{{ config('leaflet.map_center_latitude') }}, {{ config('leaflet.map_center_longitude') }}], {{ config('leaflet.zoom_level') }}
```

Las defino en un archivo de configuración de Leaflet que tengo alojado en la carpeta config de la aplicacion de laravel

A continuación accedo desde JS a la ruta de los datos y los alojo en la variable getData:

```
let getData = `{{ route('getInstallations') }}`;

    const api = new XMLHttpRequest();
    api.open('GET', getData, true);
    api.send();

    var marker = {};

    api.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            let datos = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            $.each(datos, function(index, item) {
                var instIcon = L.icon({
                    iconUrl: `/images/` + item.pin ,
                    iconSize:     [22, 32],     // size of the icon
                    iconAnchor:   [11, 32],     // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
                    popupAnchor:  [0, -33]      // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
                });

                marker = new L.marker([item.lat, item.lng], {icon: instIcon})
                    .bindPopup('<p class="popup__header"> <strong>'+ item.name + '</strong><div class="separator-2"></div>' + '<button type="button" id="sendData" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block dataModal sendData" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dataModal" >Detalles</button> </p>' ).addTo(map);
            });

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(document).on('click', '.sendData', function(){
                    var id=$(this).val(item.id);
                    var selector = '.modalTitle' + item.id;
                    alert(selector);
                    var name = $(selector).text();
                    $(".modalTitle").html(name);
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

Convierto el `getData` a otra variable `datos` y lo recorro para crear los marcadores. El resultado es algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la construcción de esos pines, les defino la opción de que posean un popup que se mostraría en:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El objetivo es que haciendo clic en "DETALLES" se abra un modal de bootstrap donde pueda mostrar el detalle del registro con sus imagenes asociadas.

El codigo del formulario modal es de bootstrap 4:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="dataModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dataModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title modalTitle" id="dataModalLabel"></h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <img class="img-fluid img-rounded" src="{{ asset('/images/generica.png') }}" alt="">
            <small class="text-muted float-right mt-2">Creado por: Usuario | 2019-12-04</small>
            <br><br>
            <p class="mt-2">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mt-3" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            @auth ()
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning mt-3">Editar</button>
            @endauth
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

El problema que tengo es que no puedo mandar los datos via ese boton generado en el código de js... 
si alguien puede darme una mano... se los recontra agradeceria

Comment: abre el modal? supongo que si, el codigo parece el correcto. en que variables esta el/los detalle(s) e imagen(url) que deseas mostrar?

Comment: Si, de hecho el botón del ejemplo de Bootstrap 4 es el que coloco dentro del popup. En modal se muestra pero vacio. De hecho puse un alert para ver si entra a la función y nada. La descripción es el campo description que viene desde el controlador. Y las imágenes tienen una relación polimorfica que luego vere como recuperar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a lo sugerido he hecho lo siguiente:

```
marker = new L.marker([item.lat, item.lng], {icon: instIcon})
   .bindPopup('<p class="popup__header"> <strong>'+ item.name + '</strong><div class="separator-2"></div>' + '<button type="button" onclick="sendData(dataID=' +  item.id + ',dataName=' + item.name + ',dataDescription='  + item.description + ')" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block dataModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dataModal" >Detalles</button> </p>' ).addTo(map);
```

Lo que interesa es la parte siguiente:

```
onclick="sendData(dataID=' +  item.id + ',dataName=' + item.name + ',dataDescription='  + item.description + ')"
```

Luego en la función, hago esto otro:

```
function sendData(dataID, dataName, dataDescription) {
        alert(dataID);
        $("#dataModalLabel").html(dataName);
        $("#dataDescription").html(dataDescription);
    }
```

Quiero aclarar que ese `alert` que está entrando a la función lo puse solo para saber si entra a la misma, pues bien, no entra. En contrapartida en la depuración, en la solapa "SOURCE" puedo ver lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Más abajo al pie de esta sección me aparece el error con letras rojas:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

por lo que parece, como estoy mandando una cadena de texto, es como que no sabe que es un texto... o se confunde con los caracteres que hay dentro ya que en muchos marcadores hay paréntesis.

---

Resuelto, tenía que poner unas comillas inclinadas en los campos que son texto y quedo bien...

```
sendData(dataID=' +  item.id + ',dataName=`' + item.name + '`,dataDescription=`'  + item.description + '`)
```

ahora si llega el titulo, la descripción y todo lo demas al modal... ahora tengo que ver como recupero las imagenes, pero eso es oooootro tema...

Answer (score 8):

Vamos por partes, primero la lógica del modal viene de:

1. Seleccionas un marker en el mapa.
2. Aparece un popup pequeño con un botón de ver detalles.
3. Si le das click en el botón de ver detalles, te debe salir un modal con los datos del marker

Ahora bien, vamos re-formulando el código que tienes:

```
marker = new L.marker([item.lat, item.lng], {icon: instIcon})
                .bindPopup('<p class="popup__header"> <strong>'+ item.name + '</strong><div class="separator-2"></div>' + '<button type="button" id="sendData" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block dataModal sendData" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dataModal" >Detalles</button> </p>' ).addTo(map);
```

Aquí defines el Id y una clase como `sendData`, que me parece algo extraño, se recomienda evitar usar el mismo nombre para ID y clase, te ahorras confusiones innecesarias. Si siempre vas a estar generando popups con el mismo, llegará un momento donde el DOM se haga ponga pesado y de paso el código puede enredarse.

Para debuggear en modo Sherlock Holmes nos preguntamos sobre el modal: ¿Será reusable? ¿Necesitaré que el mismo Id se mantenga? Para resolver de mejor manera estas preguntas, veamos la siguiente parte del código:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.sendData', function() {
        var id = $(this).val(item.id);
        var selector = '.modalTitle' + item.id;
        alert(selector);
        var name = $(selector).text();
        $(".modalTitle").html(name);
    });
});
```

Hagamos una pausa aquí. ¿Es necesario el document ready? No, ¿por qué? Porque es innecesario que se ejecute un método dentro de una función que ya ha cargado todo el documento, dicho de otro modo, si le quitamos el document ready igualito funcionará. ¿Y en qué momento necesitamos que se ejecute el document ready? Pues, cuando la página va a cargar por primera vez y necesitas inicializar valores dentro de `<select options>`, variables de estado y cosas por el estilo.

En la línea siguiente encontramos un `event listener`. Hacemos otra pausa y analizamos: ¿Cuál es el objetivo de este event listener? Según lo observado, lo que se quiere hacer es obtener los valores del elemento que se ha hecho click para proceder a seleccionar un ID de un fragmento del código del HTML que debería estar presente. Ahora bien, existen alternativas como la siguiente:

Generar una función aparte que recibe directamente el ID y llama al modal en lugar de estar a la escucha de un evento click. Dicho en código:

```
function verDetallesDelPopup(elementID) {
    var selector = '.modalTitle' + elementID;
    alert(selector);
    var name = $(selector).text();
    $(".modalTitle").html(name);
}
```

Y eso lo invocamos desde:

```
marker = new L.marker([item.lat, item.lng], {icon: instIcon})
            .bindPopup('<p class="popup__header"> <strong>'+ item.name + '</strong><div class="separator-2"></div>' + '<button type="button" onclick="verDetallesDelPopup(' + item.id +')" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block dataModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dataModal" >Detalles</button> </p>' ).addTo(map);
```

Nótese que eliminé el Id y la class "sendData".

Hasta aquí, vamos bien. Un primer detalle que me preocupa: De la función `verDetallesDelPopup`, estamos haciendo otro selector para extraer el nombre y lo ponemos dentro de TODOS los elementos que contengan una clase llamada `modalTitle`, de acuerdo al código, se encuentra en el modal del final de la pregunta:

```
<h5 class="modal-title modalTitle" id="dataModalLabel"></h5>
```

Como es un único elemento, sería más eficiente llamarlo por el selector `#dataModalLabel` de este modo:

```
    $("#dataModalLabel").html(name);
```

Un segundo dato que me preocupa, ver los comentarios dentro del código:

```
function verDetallesDelPopup(elementID) {
    var selector = '.modalTitle' + elementID; 
    //Aquí, en el selector, ¿en qué momento generas todos los modalTitle seguidos de cada elementID?
    alert(selector);
    var name = $(selector).text();
    $(".modalTitle").html(name);
}
```

Sucede que si los elementos del selector son inexistentes, te va a lanzar un error, asegúrate de tenerlos o bien, modificar el comportamiento de este código para que se adapte mejor a lo que tienes.

Comment: Gracias @fredyfx !!! Si, hay cosas que tengo que revisar. En un rato lo aplico y si funciona muestro como quedó !!!

Comment: Funciona... ahora bien por elementID envío el id del marcador, pero podría concatenar en el llamado a esa función el resto de los datos del marcador ? Quiero decir si podría enviar, por ese evento onclick la descripción, el user_id, el created_at... y recibirlo en la función ? o enviar un array y luego recorrerlo dentro de la función ?

Comment: Claro que sí. Todo es posible en la viña del señor :D veo que has aceptado la respuesta, ¿lograste hacerlo funcionar como querías o se te pasó el mouse y aceptaste la respuesta sin querer queriendo como diría el chavo del 8?

Comment: Funciona si !!! logré imprimir en el modal el ID del marcador, y se corresponde con los ids que tienen en la bd como corresponde, pero por ejemplo quise pasar en lugar del id, el name entonces en el onclick puse "item.name" pero ahi ya no funciona... hago onclick="sendData(' + item.id , item.name , item.description + ')" y en la funcion function sendData(elementID, dataName, dataDescription) y desaparece el boton...

Comment: Luego de: item.id + ',' + item.name +',' +... Y la hiciste

Comment: El botón desaparece porque el html está mal armado

Comment: Hago: onclick="sendData(' +  item.id +  ',' + item.name + ','  + item.description + ')" y en la función: function sendData(dataID, dataName, dataDescription) { y después llamo cada elemento como: $("#dataModalLabel").html(dataName); para el título y para la descripción le puse un id="dataDescription" a unas etiquetas <p> y le paso desde la función $("#dataDescription").html(dataDescription); y haciendo todo eso, no se muestra nada... si paso el id solo, pasa se imprime, se ve...

Comment: en la depuración en la solapa console aparece este mensaje en rojo: "installations:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"